# How can I neglect a update in App Store?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, software-update

How can I neglect a update in App Store since it's annoying?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right-click on the update and choose Hide Update.

You have to right-click on the white background, not on the text, for the option to appear.

[image]

To unhide updates, choose Store → Show All Software Updates (only visible if you have a hidden update).